# How to edit or view Prometheus-Alerts inside Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I read that Grafana 8 has a better integration with Prometheus Alerts. I run Grafana 8 inside a docker container and setup Prometheus data-source. It works great:

[image]

I also setup an alert from Granafa. This is not a Prometheus Alert because I don't see it inside Prometheus:

[image]

[image]

## Question

I can't find the place where I can view or edit Prometheus Alerts (***Not Grafana Alerts!***).

Is it possible? If yes, which buttons I need to click on to be able to do that?

---

Grafana image version: 8.0.6 (latest)
Prometheus image version: 2.28.1 (latest)

Answer (score 0):

To view and edit Prometheus alerts you need to click on the "Alerting" menu (the "bell" icon on the left side) but first you need to explicitly opt-in to the Grafana 8 alerts, by adding the following to the Grafana configuration file:

```
[feature_toggles]
    enable = ngalert
```

See more details in the Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/unified-alerting/opt-in/).

Comment: what about viewing a prometheus alert in Grafana?

Comment: I added more details to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the meaning of [Grafana 8.0: Unified Grafana and Prometheus alerts, live streaming, new visualizations, and more!](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/06/08/grafana-8.0-unified-grafana-and-prometheus-alerts-live-streaming-new-visualizations-and-more/) in the Grafana 8 announcement?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't note you were talking about Grafana 8. I just corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks. "you need to explicity opt-in to the Grafana 8 alerts" - I was lost from Grafana docs (That was the motivation for this question). They are not clear. I will be super gracefull for actual screenshots on what to do. Thanks mate!

Comment: I added more details to the answer.